# How to have 2 elements share an event in jQuery, and refer to that particular element

Tags: jquery

I have a simple question.

Is it possible to rewrite this code below since they both do the same thing, except modify a particular element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickShow").click(function(){
    $("#cw1").toggleClass("showLess");
    if($("#clickShow").text() === "Show more"){
      $("#clickShow").text("Show less");
    } else {
      $("#clickShow").text("Show more");
    }
  });

  $("#clickShow1").click(function(){
    $("#cw2").toggleClass("showLess");
    if($("#clickShow1").text() === "Show more"){
      $("#clickShow1").text("Show less");
    } else {
      $("#clickShow1").text("Show more");
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You should post your HTML in order to get more relevant answer.

Comment: Code review requests generally belong on the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce that to a single function, instead of repeating code for each instance, by using the same classnames on all the similar elements as identifiers instead of depending on specific IDs. Inside the event handler, modify the element that was actually clicked -- `$(this)` -- and traverse to related elements based on the DOM structure instead of (again) specific IDs.

I made the assumption here that the "cw" element immediately follows the "clickShow" element -- if that doesn't match your DOM structure you'd change the below from `$(this).next('.cw')` to whatever traversal leads to the appropriate element.

```js
$(".clickShow").click(function() {
  $(this).next('.cw').toggleClass("showLess");
    if ($(this).text() === "Show more") {
    $(this).text("Show less");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Show more");
  }
});
```

```css
.showLess {display:none}
a {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="clickShow">Show less</a>
<div class="cw">This is text revealed by the first clickshow</div>
<a href="#" class="clickShow">Show less</a>
<div class="cw">This is text revealed by the second clickshow</div>
<a href="#" class="clickShow">Show less</a>
<div class="cw">This is text revealed by the third clickshow</div>
<a href="#" class="clickShow">Show less</a>
<div class="cw">This is text revealed by the fourth clickshow</div>
```

Comment: I like your coding style :D. I used the parants() method instead of next(). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can. Use `this` to refer to the element triggered with `click`.

```
 $("#clickShow, #clickShow1").click(function(){
    $("#cw1").toggleClass("showLess");
    if($(this).text() === "Show more"){
      $(this).text("Show less");
    } else {
    $(this).text("Show more");
   }
 });
```

**EDIT**
for the case of CW, let's say you have the ff html

```
<button id='clickShow' value='1'>Show more</button>
<button id='clickShow1' value='2'>Show more</button>
```

I can then concatenate the value on my `cw`

```
 $("#clickShow, #clickShow1").click(function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    $("#cw" + currentVal).toggleClass("showLess");
    if($(this).text() === "Show more"){
      $(this).text("Show less");
    } else {
    $(this).text("Show more");
   }
 });
```

Comment: But as you can see I have two different id`s "cw1" and "cw2". There are two div`s, one with the id "cw1" and the other with the id "cw2" and there will be more div`s "cw3" ...

Comment: ah, I missed that. In these cases, I do a bit of workaround so I can pinpoint which `cw` I am referring to: by using the button's `value` perhaps.

Comment: there, I edited it to incorporate your case. Don't forget to upvote and accept answers that have helped you!

Answer (score 1):

For more flexibility, you can use class selector instead id. I don't know about what specific html case that you have. I assume you need flexible show more button for every cw text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.clickShow', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.cw').toggleClass("showLess");
    if ($(this).text() == "Show more") {
      $(this).text("Show less");
    } else {
      $(this).text("Show more");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.showLess {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='cw'>Tes 1</span>
  <button class='clickShow'>Show less</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span class='cw'>Tes 2</span>
  <button class='clickShow'>Show less</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span class='cw'>Tes 3</span>
  <button class='clickShow'>Show less</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some nice stuff with css plus javascript that will simplify your javascript code and make it easier to avoid repetition. For example you don't even need external JS for this if you revaluate the problem. And as a bonus, you won't need to keep adding classes and functions every time you add more things that need this behavior:

```css
.showLess:before {
    content: "Show less" !important;
    }
.swapable:before{
    content: "Show more"
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click text below:

  <p class="swapable" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('showLess')"></p>
  
  <p class="swapable" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('showLess')"></p>
```